# DB2 optimize large IN predicate

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a table with over 300 million records only containing key, source and hash value. The inbuilt sql of the application runs a large IN predicate on hash value in its sql to fetch the data.The sqls are performing slowly so need suggestions on how to improve the performance of the sql. I wouldn't be able to change the sql as its an internal sql already built-in the application.  So far I have tried to put in an index on the key and another on hash column but doesn't provide much help.

Comment: Start with examination of the access-plan.  Which operating-system runs your Db2-server (Z/Os, i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows) ?   Is the table compressed, range-partitioned, distributed-by-hash, or column-organized?   All these factors can be relevant.  What is the size of the result-set? What statistics are run?

Comment: its on RHEL, not sure how to identify " table compressed, range-partitioned, distributed-by-hash, or column-organized". Size of the result set is usually like small like 100-1000 values.I have run this "RUNSTATS ON TABLE XXXXX WITH DISTRIBUTION AND SAMPLED DETAILED INDEXES ALL"

Comment: Ask your DBA if you have one, or just read the DDL. Get the *access plan* (e.g. db2exfmt or db2expln). Which Db2-version and fixpack ?

Comment: Its on 11.1. Ok, Ill ask him tomorrow. do you think partitioning will help?

Comment: *Start* with the access plan. Don't solution anything until you've analyzed the access plan.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could create a table, perhaps a temporary table (which can also accept indices), containing the values in the `IN` predicate of your current query.  Then, a simple inner join of your original query to this table would have the same effect, except it might be substantially faster if DB2 can take advantage of the index.  You would need to make sure that the columns involved in the join both have an index.

Comment: The sqls are pre-built in the application which I can't change

Comment: @WaseemAhmed Fair enough, this is what I would try first if possible.  Most databases already optimize a long `IN` clause by, e.g., building a hash of the values for slightly better performance.  I will leave this up until you get the silver bullet answer I hope you will get.

Answer (score 0):

You (or your DBA) might like to try the Design Advisor to advise on new indexes etc.

This can be run from the command line tool `db2advis` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005144.html

Or from Data Server Manager which provides a Web Based front end for the
Query Advisor and Access Path Advisor. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048195